# C# OR statement in string.Contains

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
        if (_strInput.Contains("xxx") && _strInput.Contains("yyy" || "zzz"))
        {
            _strOutput[0] = "Success";
        }
```

but i get this error:

Error   1   Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Basically what I'm looking for is one value to exist in a string and one value from a selection of values to exist. Any help would be amazing, thanks in advance!

Comment: This about it this way: What would the expression `"yyy" || "zzz"` mean? You won't be able to answer that.

Comment: @usr: Exactly, and also: What data type would the expression (or the result thereof) have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a common occurrence in your code base you can use an extension method.

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static bool ContainsAny(this string str, params string[] values)
    {
        return values.Any(x => str.Contains(x));
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
"abcd".ContainsAny("a", "c"); //True
"abcd".ContainsAny("z"); //False
"abcd".ContainsAny("z", "ac", "ab") //True
```

So your code would end up looking like

```
if (_strInput.Contains("xxx") && _strInput.ContainsAny("yyy", "zzz"))
{
    _strOutput[0] = "Success";
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why this answer was marked as accepted and then subsequently unmarked?  Was an error found?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you mean this?

```
    if (_strInput.Contains("xxx") && (_strInput.Contains("yyy") || _strInput.Contains("zzz"))
    {
        _strOutput[0] = "Success";
    }
```

What this will do is execute only if _strInput contains 'xxx' and either 'yyy' or 'zzz'.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use both strings in one `Contains`, wrap them in parentheses:

```
if (_strInput.Contains("xxx") &&( _strInput.Contains("yyy") 
                               || _strInput.Contains("zzz"))
{
    _strOutput[0] = "Success";
}
```

So the string must contain "xxx" and either "yyy" or "zzz".

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I didn't want to repeat _strInput.Contains, but if I have to I guess I have to =] thanks again for the very fast replies ^.^

Comment: @PaulBaronGikkingen: If it's important for you to avoid repeating you could define a collection of allowed strings like `var allowed=new[]{"xxx","yyy"}`. Then you can use this on the right side: `&& allowed.Any(s => _strInput.Contains(s))`

Comment: @PaulBaronGikkingen If all of our posts helped, please uprate all of them and choose one of them as the accepted answer.